# Exploding rows of a pandas dataframe given a 'mapping dataframe'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, mapping

I have to dataframes. I need to perform a manipulation on dataframe A. It looks like this:

| name | score |
| --- | --- |
| alpha | 16 |
| beta | 12 |
| gamma | 24 |
| delta | 16 |

The second dataframe, B, is a mapping.

| name_in | name_out | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| beta | beta_1 | 0.5 |
| beta | beta_2 | 0.3 |
| beta | beta_3 | 0.2 |
| omega | omega_1 | 0.9 |
| omega | omega_2 | 0.1 |

If I perform the mapping on dataframe A, I need the following outcome:

| name | score |
| --- | --- |
| alpha | 16 |
| beta_1 | 6 |
| beta_2 | 3.6 |
| beta_3 | 2.4 |
| gamma | 24 |
| delta | 16 |

So, conceptually, I need an algorithm that checks if the name occurs in the mapping dataframe. If it does, I need to duplicate the row for as many values exist in the mapping. Also, I need to multiply the duplicated scores with the weight of the mapping.

The procedure basically adds a level of detail, given the mapping.

Comment: Why 'alpha' in the output table is 14? It does not appear in the mapping table.

Comment: Was a typo, thanks for notifying me. Values in dataframe A that do not occur in the mapping stay untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) followed by [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna) to fill out missing values:

```
# Merge Tables Together
new_df = df_a.merge(df_b, left_on='name', right_on='name_in', how='left')

# Fillna with Name
new_df['name_out'] = new_df['name_out'].fillna(new_df['name'])
# Calculate Scores and fillna
new_df['weight'] = (new_df['weight'] * new_df['score']).fillna(new_df['score'])

# Cleanup columns
new_df = (
    new_df.drop(columns=['name', 'score', 'name_in'])
        .rename(columns={'name_out': 'name', 'weight': 'score'})
)
```

`new_df`:

```
     name  score
0   alpha   16.0
1  beta_1    6.0
2  beta_2    3.6
3  beta_3    2.4
4   gamma   24.0
5   delta   16.0
```

Comment: You're the best!